# Angular 13 get Value And Label from Select Option

Tags: angular

i want to get the value and label of my select option and mapp the to my reactive Form.
this is my html:

```
  <select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event.target)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="C1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="C2">Country 2</option>
    <option value="C3">Country 3</option>
  </select>
```

and this is my ts code :

```
  onChange(event: any) {
    // here i want to get the value and label of my selected item (C2 , Country 2 for example)
    console.log(event.value); // this print only the value C1,2,3
  }
```

Comment: Maybe [value]="{ value: C1, label: ‘Country 1’” works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Answer

HTML:

```
 <select (change)="onChange($event)" formControlName="country"></select>
```

TS:

```
  onChange($event: any) {
    let text = $event.target.options[$event.target.options.selectedIndex].text;

    this.yourForm.patchValue({ labelText: text });

    console.log(text);
  }
```

The `(change)` should get the text that represents the option, and the `formControlName` should retrieve the value from the option.

`patchValue` will change the form value for the value that you want, you just need to type the name of the formControl: `labelText` and after the `:` the desired value!

About the value from the option, if you have a `formControlName` on the select, it will automatically change the `formControl` value!

Answer (score 1):

In your component.ts
declare a variable / collection

```
options = [
  {value:'some value', label:'some label'}, 
  {value:'some value', label:'some label'}, 
  {value:'some value', label:'some label'}
];
public anothervariableToHoldTheSelectedOption = null;
```

in component.html file

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="anothervariableToHoldTheSelectedOption">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="option">{{option.label}}</option>
  </select>
```

In this way you will have a whole object in the holdingObject. you can do anything with it.